# sumifs and countifs equivalent in R

Tags: r, dplyr, countif, sumifs

guys

Say I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
id   value   year   total_value  total_frequency
1      10    2019       44             4
1      15    2019       44             4
1      12    2020       44             4
1      7     2020       44             4
2      10    2019       28             2
2      18    2020       28             2
3      27    2019       27             1
```

I intend to achieve a form like this:

```
id   value   year   total_value  total_frequency  2020_value  2020_frequency
1      10    2019       44             4              19           2
1      15    2019       44             4              19           2
1      12    2020       44             4              19           2
1      7     2020       44             4              19           2
2      10    2019       28             2              18           1
2      18    2020       28             2              18           1
3      27    2019       27             1               0           0
```

The repetition is necessary for future steps.

I can easily achieve this form via Excel using sumifs() and countifs(), but unable to get the same result in R.

I think I can use `dplyr` package to do this but don't know exactly how, hence some advice is needed.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you obtained the final two columns? sumifs and countifs of what?

Comment: Say 'id' column is in column A in excel and so on, 2020_value is calculated as =sumifs($A:$A,A1,$B:$B,2020). 2020_frequency =countifs($A:$A,A1,$C:$C,2020).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by `id` and `sum` the `value` for the `year` in 2020 and count the number of rows for it as well.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value_2020 = sum(value[year %in% 2020]), 
          frequency_2020 = sum(year %in% 2020)) %>%
  ungroup

#     id value  year total_value total_frequency value_2020 frequency_2020
#  <int> <int> <int>       <int>           <int>      <int>          <int>
#1     1    10  2019          44               4         19              2
#2     1    15  2019          44               4         19              2
#3     1    12  2020          44               4         19              2
#4     1     7  2020          44               4         19              2
#5     2    10  2019          28               2         18              1
#6     2    18  2020          28               2         18              1
#7     3    27  2019          27               1          0              0
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c('value_2020', 'frequency_2020') := {i1 <- year %in% 2020
            .(sum(value[i1]), sum(i1))}, id]
```

-output

```
 df1
   id value year total_value total_frequency value_2020 frequency_2020
1:  1    10 2019          44               4         19              2
2:  1    15 2019          44               4         19              2
3:  1    12 2020          44               4         19              2
4:  1     7 2020          44               4         19              2
5:  2    10 2019          28               2         18              1
6:  2    18 2020          28               2         18              1
7:  3    27 2019          27               1          0              0
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `tapply`

```
transform(
  df,
  value_2020 = tapply(value, list(year, id), sum)["2020", ][id],
  frequency_2020 = tapply(year == 2020, list(year, id), sum)["2020", ][id]
)
```

gives

```
  id value year total_value total_frequency value_2020 frequency_2020
1  1    10 2019          44               4         19              2
2  1    15 2019          44               4         19              2
3  1    12 2020          44               4         19              2
4  1     7 2020          44               4         19              2
5  2    10 2019          28               2         18              1
6  2    18 2020          28               2         18              1
7  3    27 2019          27               1         NA             NA
```